# listKeys problems in ARM template using inside variables or parameters

Tags: azure-devops, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I'm setting up an ARM template for my Azure Functions. I have `functions_app.json` which will function as the "main" template and will be used for other release pipelines as well.

Then there will be project specific parameter templates, like:

- counter_function_arm.parameters.test.json
- counter_function_arm.parameters.acceptance.json
- weather_function_arm.parameters.test.json

etc.

But I'm stuck at this part where it creates the actual Function resource inside the `functions_app.json` template:

```json
"resources": [
{
    "apiVersion": "2018-11-01",
    "name": "[variables('resourceName')]",
    "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
    "properties": {
        "name": "[variables('resourceName')]",
        "siteConfig": {
            "appSettings": [
                {
                    "name": "FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION",
                    "value": "~4"
                },
                {
                    "name": "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME",
                    "value": "dotnet"
                },
                {
                    "name": "AzureWebJobsStorage",
                    "value": "[concat('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=',variables('storageAccountName'),';AccountKey=',listKeys(resourceId('xxxx-xxxx','MyResourceGroup','Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('storageAccountName')), '2019-06-01').keys[0].value,';EndpointSuffix=','core.windows.net')]"
                },
                {
                    "name": "WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING",
                    "value": "[concat('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=',variables('storageAccountName'),';AccountKey=',listKeys(resourceId('xxxx-xxxx','MyResourceGroup','Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('storageAccountName')), '2019-06-01').keys[0].value,';EndpointSuffix=','core.windows.net')]"
                },
                {
                    "name": "WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE",
                    "value": "[toLower(variables('resourceName'))]"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I left some things out for brevity. The import part is the `appSettings` section.

My initial idea was to put that `array` in `variables`. Those will be the "default" settings. Then from my `counter_function_arm.parameters.test.json` file I would add another array specific to that application and then `union` those two together so all `AppSettings` are configured.

Something like this:

counter_function_arm.parameters.test.json

```json
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "customAppSettings":{
            "value": [
                {
                    "name": "CustomProperty",
                    "value": "some value"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

functions_app.json

```json
"variables": {
    "defaultAppSettings": [
                {
                    "name": "FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION",
                    "value": "~4"
                },
                {
                    "name": "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME",
                    "value": "dotnet"
                },
                {
                    "name": "AzureWebJobsStorage",
                    "value": "[concat('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=',variables('storageAccountName'),';AccountKey=',listKeys(resourceId('xxxx-xxxx','MyResourceGroup','Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('storageAccountName')), '2019-06-01').keys[0].value,';EndpointSuffix=','core.windows.net')]"
                },
                {
                    "name": "WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING",
                    "value": "[concat('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=',variables('storageAccountName'),';AccountKey=',listKeys(resourceId('xxxx-xxxx','MyResourceGroup','Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('storageAccountName')), '2019-06-01').keys[0].value,';EndpointSuffix=','core.windows.net')]"
                },
                {
                    "name": "WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE",
                    "value": "[toLower(variables('resourceName'))]"
                }
            ]
},
"resources": [
{
    "apiVersion": "2018-11-01",
    "name": "[variables('resourceName')]",
    "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
    "properties": {
        "name": "[variables('resourceName')]",
        "siteConfig": {
            "appSettings": "[union(variables('defaultAppSettings'), parameters('customAppSettings'))]"
        }
    }
}
```

So in this case I `union` the variable `variables('defaultAppSettings')` and `parameters('customAppSettings')` together.

But, the problem is that I can't use `listKeys` in the `variables` section. I also can't move this to the `parameters` section and set it as `defaultValue` because `listKeys` is also not allowed there.

Adding a hard coded array to `union` also doesn't work:

```json
"appSettings": "[union([1,2,3], parameters('customAppSettings'))]"
```

So I am out of ideas.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a way around this, it is not pretty but it works... Basically I have an array of purely static app settings (in your case FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION,  FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME, WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE) that you can create in variables, an array of customAppSettings from parameters, and another array that I have to write as raw JSON.
Here's an example :

```
"resources": [
    {
        "apiVersion": "2018-11-01",
        "name": "[variables('resourceName')]",
        "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
        "properties": {
            "name": "[variables('resourceName')]",
            "siteConfig": {
                "appSettings": "[union(variables('staticAppSettings'), parameters('customAppSettings'), json(concat('[{\"name\": \"AzureWebJobsStorage\",\"value\": \"', concat('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=', parameters('azureFunctionParameters').functionStorageName,';AccountKey=', listKeys(resourceId(parameters('azureFunctionParameters').mainStorageResourceGroup, 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', parameters('azureFunctionParameters').functionStorageName), '2021-08-01').keys[1].value, ';EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net'),'\"}]')))]"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Sadly this is the best I could come up with, it is very prone to syntax error but if you're using [multi-line strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/syntax#multi-line-strings) you could format it in a way to avoid errors (but be careful if you're using Azure Devops it is not compatible).

EDIT :
There is another way to accomplish this that may be more suitable for you, which is to use a linkedTemplate :

Main template

```
"resources": [
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
        "apiVersion": "2021-04-01",
        "name": "yourResourceDeployment",
        "properties": {
            "mode": "Incremental",
            "templateLink": {
                "uri": "[concat(parameters('blobBaseUrl'), '/', parameters('resourceGroupName'), '/azurefunctions/baseazurefunction.json')]",
                "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0"
            },
            "parameters": {
                "azureFunctionParameters": {
                    "value": "[parameters('baseAzureFunctionParameters')]"
                },
                "appSettings": {
                    "value" : "[union(variables('staticAppSettings'), parameters('customAppSettings'))]"
                },
                "someMoreAppSettings": {
                    "value" : [
                        {
                            "name": "AzureWebJobsStorage",
                            "value": "[concat('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=',variables('storageAccountName'),';AccountKey=',listKeys(resourceId('xxxx-xxxx','MyResourceGroup','Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('storageAccountName')), '2019-06-01').keys[0].value,';EndpointSuffix=','core.windows.net')]"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING",
                            "value": "[concat('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=',variables('storageAccountName'),';AccountKey=',listKeys(resourceId('xxxx-xxxx','MyResourceGroup','Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('storageAccountName')), '2019-06-01').keys[0].value,';EndpointSuffix=','core.windows.net')]"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

In the baseazurefunction.json linkedTemplate you can just use

```
{
    "apiVersion": "2018-11-01",
    "name": "[variables('resourceName')]",
    "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
    "properties": {
        "name": "[variables('resourceName')]",
        "siteConfig": {
            "appSettings": "[union(parameters('appSettings'), parameters('moreAppSettings'))]"
        }
    }
}
```

If you have a security concern over sending connection strings as parameters to other templates, you could wrap your appsettings in a secureobject with a property called array which would contain all your settings and then use it like this instead

```
    "appSettings": {
        "type": "secureobject",
        "metadata": {
            "description": "Secure object with an array property which contains the appsettings"
        }
    },
    "moreAppSettings": {
        "type": "secureobject",
        "metadata": {
            "description": "Secure object with an array property which contains more appsettings"
        }
    }

    .
    .
    .

    "appSettings": "[union(parameters('appSettings').array, parameters('moreAppSettings').array)]"
```

Comment: Thanks, I went with your first example. It isn't pretty, but it seems to work in my releases.

Answer (score 0):

I took inspiration from James Hyot's answer and tweaked it a little to work with **Azure DevOps Deployment**.

This how I combined three arrays including WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING and AzureWebJobsStorage setting for a Function App.

```
"appSettings": "[union(
            variables('defaultFunctionAppSettings'),
            parameters('config').appSettings,
            createArray(
              createObject(
                string('name'), string('AzureWebJobsStorage'),
                string('value'), string(concat('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=', parameters('funcStorageName'), ';AccountKey=', listKeys(resourceId('{resourceGroupId}', 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', parameters('funcStorageName')),'2022-09-01').keys[0].value))
              )
            ),
            createArray(
              createObject(
                string('name'), string('WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING'),
                string('value'), string(concat('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=', parameters('funcStorageName'), ';AccountKey=', listKeys(resourceId('{resourceGroupId}', 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', parameters('funcStorageName')),'2022-09-01').keys[0].value))
              )
            )
          )]"
```

Hope this can help someone out there.